# Why is List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>) faster than new List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)

Tags: c#, .net, performance, list, ienumerable

I heard that  `List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)` faster than `new List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`. After looking in reflector I could not tell why ad once I created a test application Indeed I saw that it is faster.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Could you paste your sample code?  Their performance will differ depending on the objects you are passing in.

Comment: "I heard that ..." - don't believe everything you hear, especially blanket statements about performance.

Comment: @Joe It came from someone who knows his stuff....

Comment: "It came from someone who knows his stuff...." - An Appeal to Authority (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_authority) isn't convincing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I can't confirm your assumption. AddRange was always slower than the constructor variant.

I made some test code for it:

a) `var list = new List<T>(enumerable);`

is faster than

b) `var list = new List<T>(); list.AddRange(enumerable);`

tested with different IEnumerables

> List: new: 32ms   addrange: 47ms
>
> LinkedList: new: 58ms   addrange: 99ms
>
> HashSet: new: 56ms   addrange: 98ms
>
> Queue: new: 271ms   addrange: 516ms

Comment: I'm sure that the overhead is negligible.

Comment: That's not what OP has asked. Since you're passing a `List<T>` to the constructor, it can simply be used to be copied into the new list whereas passing an `IEnumarable<T>` (f.e. `Enumerable.Range(1,1000000)`) may require that the enumerable must be enumerated and added one by one to the new List. Apart from that i assume that the difference in your example is negligible anyway.

Comment: An IEnumerable can be of all different types. That does not neglect the fact that a new operator will add additional overhead in both cases. I don't know on what fact he bases his assumption that AddRange is faster. I can't confirm that at all.

Comment: Just a guess. Maybe the constructor depends on the effort of the Count function which is fast for a list.

Comment: I acctialy got the same conclusion so I was surprized